# how to get the dimensions of a 3D array?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation, multidimensional-array

I am happy to find in C++11 that we can allocate multiple dimensions with "auto", but I get strange dimension values with the definition "auto a=new float[10][20][30]" and " float a1[10][20][30]". Please help to check out and any possible solutions.

=============a.cpp =========================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
size_t size(T const & a ) {  return sizeof a / sizeof (a[0]);}

int main(){
auto  a=new float[10][20][30];
float a1[10][20][30];
std::cout<<size(a)<<" "<<size(a[0])<<"  "<<size(a[0][0])<<"\n";
std::cout<<size(a1)<<" "<<size(a1[0])<<"  "<<size(a1[0][0])<<"\n";
delete[] a;
}
```

==========result========================

> XUs-Mac-mini:Desktop XU$ g++ -std=c++11 a.cpp -o a
>
> XUs-Mac-mini:Desktop XU$ a
>
> 0 20  30
>
> 10 20  30

Comment: Thanks, Barak. when using "auto a", sizeof (a) is 8, no the memory size of the whole array, that is the problem to use "auto". it works fine when you define with "float a[10][20][30]"

Comment: For Paul Evans:  [type of `a`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da10b5b4b547dd2d).

Comment: Your problem is not the `auto`, but the fact that `a` is initialized to point to a dynamically-allocated memory segment. The method that I suggested can only work for a **statically-allocated** array.

Comment: A more accurate size function would be `template<class T, size_t L> size_t size(T (&)[L]) {return L;}`.  It would also reveal the source of your problem: namely that `a1` is an array, and `a` is _not_ an array.

Comment: @barakmanos: The fact that the method was demonstrated twice to work on dynamically allocated arrays shows that your comment is at least partially (technically?) wrong.

Comment: Also: `std::extent<decltype(a1),DIMENSION>::value` gets the an arbitrary subarray size

Answer (score 2):

You can use templates to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
static size_t countof_0(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
    return c0;
}

template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
static size_t countof_1(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
    return c1;
}

template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
static size_t countof_2(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
    return c2;
}

int main() {
    double my_3d_array[21][11][32];

    std::cout << countof_0(my_3d_array) << "\n";
    std::cout << countof_1(my_3d_array) << "\n";
    std::cout << countof_2(my_3d_array) << "\n";
}
```

If you can make the functions constexpr, then you should.

Comment: It is a very good idea, Thanks a lot Chris!  Can we get another general function for handle any dimension array?

Comment: All I can think of to support more dimensions would be to overload each function with versions for arrays with different dimensions. Maybe there is a way to do it with variadic template arguments.  I'm also trying to figure out how to do this with your dynamic array, but unfortunately the array's type does not include the count for the major dimension.

Comment: The programmer is responsible for the bookkeeping of the size of dynamically allocated arrays. `new float[10][20][30]` gives you a `float (*)[20][30]` and it's your job to remember you allocated 10 of  `float[20][30]`. There's no way around that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Jrok. but in a lot of case, I am a bit tried to keep in mind how many exactly the first dimension is, that is why in C, you always pass a parameters to tell the function the array dimension. In fortran, it is already done. C++ should be more flexible on this. Sorry, Jrok, I don't have much coding experience, just want to write some computational code, rather than good software.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code based on Chiris' idea above, unto 5 dimensions, likes good though:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get Dimension from 5D array
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3,size_t c4>
        static size_t size1(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3][c4]) {
            return c0;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3,size_t c4>
        static size_t size2(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3][c4]) {
            return c1;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3,size_t c4>
        static size_t size3(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3][c4]) {
            return c2;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3,size_t c4>
        static size_t size4(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3][c4]) {
            return c3;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3,size_t c4>
        static size_t size5(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3][c4]) {
            return c4;
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get Dimension from 4D array
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3>
        static size_t size1(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3]) {
            return c0;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3>
        static size_t size2(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3]) {
            return c1;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3>
        static size_t size3(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3]) {
            return c2;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2,size_t c3>
        static size_t size4(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2][c3]) {
            return c3;
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get Dimension from 3D array
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
        static size_t size1(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
            return c0;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
        static size_t size2(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
            return c1;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1, size_t c2>
        static size_t size3(const T (&arr)[c0][c1][c2]) {
            return c2;
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get Dimension from 2D array
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1>
        static size_t size1(const T (&arr)[c0][c1]) {
            return c0;
        }
        template <typename T, size_t c0, size_t c1>
        static size_t size2(const T (&arr)[c0][c1] ) {
            return c1;
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        //Get Dimension from 1D array
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        template <typename T, size_t c0>
        static size_t size1(const T (&arr)[c0]) {
            return c0;
        }


        /*
        int main() {
            float my_3d_array[11][22][33][44] ;

            cout << size1(my_3d_array) << "\n";
            cout << size2(my_3d_array) << "\n";
            cout << size3(my_3d_array) << "\n";
            cout << size4(my_3d_array) << "\n";    
        }*/
```

Comment: Or, another way, more like your idea: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b323f6ac8b173c22